# How to find a rational solution from an inequality involving rationals

Tags: real-analysis

How could I find a rational $k$ such that $ (p-k)^2 > 2 $ for any rational $p > 0 \,?$ Assume that I don't any knowledge of $R$, only upto $Q$ is known to me.

Comment: Try $k = -\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the minimal *k* than it means the closest rational to $\sqrt2$,which dose not exist (acording Bhaskara-Brouncker algorithm if you want me to show you why just write it as a comment ).

Answer (score 0):

Any $k < -\sqrt{2}$ will work.

For a given $k$, you want to solve $f(p) = p^2 - 2kp - k^2- 2 > 0$, so therefore you first solve when $f(p) = 0$, i.e.

$p = \frac{2k \pm \sqrt{4k^2 - 4(k^2 - 2)}}{2} = k \pm \sqrt{2}$.

Since $f(p)$ will be first positive, then negative, then positive, the negative area will be between $k - \sqrt{2}$ and $k + \sqrt{2}$, so since we want to make sure that $f(p) > 0$ for all $p > 0$, then we want to make sure that $k + \sqrt{2} < 0$, i.e. $k < -\sqrt{2}$.